# Relational database - Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build relations with my database tables. Im having a tutorial lesson at the moment with 3 tables. for example (auth_user table, partyEvent table, friends table).

Now a user should be able to create just one partyEvent. Friends can join any number of partyEvent created by the users. 
The owner id in the Friends model tells the partyEvent and User 'the friend' belongs to.

I am able to restrict the users to create only one partyEvent. But when i try to register friends to a partyEvent, the owner's id is not sent. Instead the default value in:

```
owner = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', related_name = 'party', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
```

is rather sent. Why is that happening?

**models**

```
class PartyEvent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    owner = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', related_name = 'party', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')

class Friends(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',related_name = 'friends', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
```

**serializers**

```
class FriendsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.id')
    class Meta:
        model = Friends
        fields = ('id','name','owner')
```

Comment: I don't see where you assign a friend to a party event. Along with the friend, do you provide owner or party id?

Comment: @hurturk, i assign friend to the user. Once i assign friend to a user, i will be able to know the paryEvent the friend belongs to. I hope i am clear enough :)

Comment: I guess in your `FriendsSerializer` owner shouldn't be a `ReadOnlyField` so your view can assign the input on create. Have you tried commenting out that line?

Comment: @hurturk, when i comment out that line, i get all the users in my database in a select input. Depending on which user is selected, the id is sent to the database. Its a good step for me now, but i want to know how it will only display just the logged in user

Comment: How about `owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())` ? That way all you need is to fill the name of the friend. I assume the party owner is logged-in and adding friends.

Comment: @hurturk  That did the job.Thanks a lot

Comment: Great! I just undeleted my answer. I thought I misunderstood previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set current user by assigning `serializers.CurrentUserDefault()` as your serializer field default. Here is an example from the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault):

```
owner = serializers.HiddenField(
    default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
)
```